# How to install fractal in Laravel project?

Tags: laravel

I installed fractal in laravel project using `composer require league/fractal` but show me error `Call to undefined function App\Services\fractal()`. Someone help me resolve this problem ?

Comment: Edit your question with service class where you execute that function.

Answer (score -1):

1. Using Fractal:
   Once you've installed Fractal, you need to create transformers for your data models and use the Fractal Manager to transform and serialize your data.

Example usage in a controller:

```
use League\Fractal\Manager;
use App\Transformers\UserTransformer;

class UserController extends Controller
 {
   public function show($id)
    {
    $user = User::find($id);

    $fractal = new Manager();
    $resource = new Item($user, new UserTransformer());

    return response()->json($fractal->createData($resource)->toArray());
  }
}
```

In this example, UserTransformer is a class you would define to transform your User model data into the desired format using Fractal's capabilities.

2.Creating Transformers:
Transformers define how your data models should be transformed into the desired format. You'll need to create transformers for your models. Here's a simple example of a transformer:

```
use League\Fractal\TransformerAbstract;

class UserTransformer extends TransformerAbstract
  {
     public function transform(User $user)
      {
         return [
            'id' => $user->id,
            'name' => $user->name,
            // other attributes
         ];
      }
   }
```

Make sure to adjust the namespaces, class names, and overall structure according to your project's needs.

Remember that Laravel doesn't provide a fractal() function out of the box. Instead, you work directly with the Fractal Manager and Transformers to achieve the desired data transformation and serialization.